# Scraping a website with python 3 that requires login

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanicalsoup

Just a question regarding some scraping authentication.  Using `BeautifulSoup`:

```
#importing the requests lib  
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#specifying the page
page = requests.get("http://localhost:8080/login?from=%2F")
#parsing through the api
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

From here the output, I think would be important:

```
 <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
     User:
    </td>
    <td>
     <input autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" id="j_username" name="j_username" type="text"/>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     Password:
    </td>
    <td>
     <input name="j_password" type="password"/>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td align="right">
     <input id="remember_me" name="remember_me" type="checkbox"/>
    </td>
    <td>
     <label for="remember_me">
      Remember me on this computer
     </label>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

This scrapes the website fine, but it requires a login. Here I am using the `mechanicalsoup` library:

```
import mechanicalsoup

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.open("http://localhost:8080/login?from=%2F")
browser.get_url()
browser.get_current_page()
browser.get_current_page().find_all('form')
browser["j_username"] = "admin"
browser ["j_password"] = "password"
browser.launch_browser()
```

However it still won't let me login.

Has anyone used a scraping tool for python 3 that lets them scrape a site that has authentication?

Comment: You could into using something like Selenium. It allows you to interact with the website to do things like a login.

Comment: have you tried the requests methods for auth? http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you're using requests. The syntax for logging in to a site is as follows:

```
import requests
page = requests.get("http://localhost:8080/login?from=%2F", auth=
('username', 'password'))
```

Hope this helps! You can read more about authentication here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/

Answer (score 1):

With MechanicalSoup, you first need to specify the form you want to fill-in and submit. If you have only one form, use:

```
browser.select_form()
```

Then, after filling-in the form, you need to submit it:

```
browser.submit_selected()
```

You may read the (newly written) [MechanicalSoup tutorial](http://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) or look at examples like [logging in into GitHub with MechanicalSoup](https://github.com/MechanicalSoup/MechanicalSoup/blob/master/examples/example.py).