# python web-scraping through a login website

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping

Looking for some help scraping a website that requires a login. Essentially the website is to get trading card prices (that I believe are from ebay) but in a format that allows search beyond the 90 days that is on ebays site. Login url is https://members.pwccmarketplace.com/login The url I search from is https://members.pwccmarketplace.com/ I searched the previous posts and found one I thought I could try replicate but to no success. Below is the code, any help whether it could work or not would be appreciated.

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47438699/scraping-a-website-with-python-3-that-requires-login
import requests
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io
import time
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from urllib.parse import quote

Product_name = []
Price = []
Date_sold = []

url = "https://www.pwccmarketplace.com/login"
values = {"email": "xyz@abc.com",
          "password": "password"}

session = requests.Session()

r = session.post(url, data=values)

Search_name = input("Search for: ")
Exclude_terms = input("Exclude these terms (- infront of all, no spaces): ")
qstr = quote(Search_name)
qstrr = quote(Exclude_terms)
Number_pages = int(input("Number of pages you want searched (Number -1): "))

pages = np.arange(1, Number_pages)

for page in pages:

    params = {"Category": 6, "deltreeid": 6, "do": "Delete Tree"}
    url = "https://www.pwccmarketplace.com/market-price-research?q=" + qstr + "+" + qstrr + "&year_min=2004&year_max=2020&price_min=0&price_max=10000&sort_by=date_desc&sale_type=auction&items_per_page=250&page=" + str(page)

    result = session.get(url, data=params)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "lxml")

    search = soup.find_all('tr')

    sleep(randint(2,10))

    for container in search:
```

Code continues but not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a token sent in the payload when you perform the `POST https://members.pwccmarketplace.com/login`. This token is located in an `input` tag and can be scraped using beautifulsoup :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.Session()

email = "your@email.com"
password = "your_password"

r = session.get("https://members.pwccmarketplace.com/login")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
token = soup.find("input", { "name": "_token"})["value"]

r = session.post(
    "https://members.pwccmarketplace.com/login",
    data = {
        "_token": token,
        "redirect": "",
        "email": email,
        "password": password,
        "remember": "true"
    }
)
```

Comment: Brilliant bertrand worked a treat, now onto the next question :D